# Diferença entre Getter\Setter e Property no Delphi

Tags: delphi

Existem algumas formas de encapsular os atributos, dentre elas, a que achei mais interessante foi a que usa os métodos `Getter` e `Setters` para acessar os atributos(Semelhante ao que se faz em Java). 
Estive lendo e baixando material sobre o assunto, e percebi que a maioria dos programadores utiliza as *properties*. Não consigo entender a "vantagem" de se usar property, pois no final das contas, elas também estão "acessando" o valor dos atributos através dos Getter e Setters.
Não sei se consegui me expressar com clareza, mas resumindo, gostaria de saber qual a diferença ou desvantagens entre elas.

Answer (score 3):

Baseando-me apenas em experiência digo que utilizar métodos, um método para obter o valor e outro para setar o valor, é um desgaste de código desnecessário a não ser que você tenha regras (validações/verificações) a serem feitas sobre o valor que será obtido ou setado ao ***field***.

Em **Delphi**, o padrão de codigo utilizado é, por exemplo:

```pascal
TPessoa = class
private
  FNome: string;
public
  property Nome: string read FNome write FNome;
end;
// e usa-se assim
pessoa := TPessoa.Create;
pessoa.Nome := 'Fulano';
```

Onde há uma propriedade `Nome` que acessa diretamente o ***field*** `FNome` (em  ***Delphi*** é ***field*** e não **atributo**).
O mesmo poderia ser escrito da seguinte forma:

```pascal
TPessoa = class
private
  FNome: string;
  private SetNome(AValue: string);
  function GetNome: string;
public
  property Nome: string read GetNome write SetNome;
end;
...
private TPessoa.SetNome(AValue: string);
begin
  // possíveis verificações e validações ...
  FNome := AValue;
end;

procedure TPessoa.GetNome: string;
begin
  // possíveis verificações e validações ...
  result := FNome;
end;
```

Aqui usa-se da mesma forma:

```
pessoa := TPessoa.Create;
pessoa.Nome := 'Fulano';
```

Dessa forma você usa intrinsicamente o método `GetNome` ao tentar recuperar o valor da propriedade e o `SetNome` para setar o valor.

Aqui é onde você provavelmente se questionou sobre a necessidade de utilizar a `property` com métodos ***Get*** e ***Set***, e que provavelmente questionou do porque não usar apenas os métodos ***SetXXX*** e ***GetXXX***, como no exemplo?

```pascal
TPessoa = class
private
  FNome: string;
public
  private SetNome(AValue: string);
  function GetNome: string;
end;
```

O padrão com `property` é um costume que vêm de tempos.
Para **C#**, com o tempo foi permitido escrever propriedades com métodos anônimos:

```cs
public class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}

// e você usa assim:
var pessoa = new Pessoa();
pessoa.Nome = 'Fulano';
```

E a questão principal do seu gosto é, muito provavelmente, pela seu costume com ***Java***.

Se não me engano, com o ***Java 8*** a propriedade com métodos anônimos já é possível. Bom, principalmente se não estiver engano, me leva a conclusão de que esse método tem sido considerado cada vez mais prático do que acessar valores de ***fields*** somente por métodos ***Get*** e ***Set***.

Finalmente, como disse que estava me baseando apenas em experiência própria, o de qual padrão de codificação a ser utilizado não é uma obrigação mas sim opicional, então te resta avaliar se a aplicação em Delphi receberá manutenção apenas por você ou se vai para outros com experiência apenas em Delphi. Se diante disso ainda quer apenas usar os métodos ***Getters*** e ***Setters***.

A diferença de uso entre uma forma e outra acredito que seja apenas no esforço a mais para o utilizador da **classe** acessar um ***field*** por meio de métodos do que diretamente pela propriedade.

Sobre as vantagens e desvantagens: acredito que há apenas vantagens em se utilizar os padrões de codificação de cada linguagem, pelo fato de tornar mais inteligível por um outro programador que venha a por a mão no seu código fonte.

Acredito que todos que programam em uma determinada linguagem e depois precisam programar em outra tendem a querer utilizar o mesmo padrão de codificação em ambas.

Comment: Suas resposta esta boa. Eu adicionaria informações sobre a integração que o delphi faz com os componentes (propriedades publicadas), diretivas (default, nodefault, storage), sobreescrita de propriedades, propriedades read-only e write-ony. Não vou fazer uma resposta pois sou muito preguiçoso

Comment: Não conheço `nodefault` e `storage` já vi mas não sei como funciona. Propriedade `write-only`? Bom, depois vou pesquisar sobre o que não sei. Obrigado pelo comentário.

Comment: rs, stored, não storage, erro de digitação.

Answer (score 2):

A sua dificuldade é justamente porque não está acostumado em ver o código assim. Pelo visto, o Java não possuía propriedades antes e é por isso que utiliza getters/setters.

Algumas vantagens em utilizar propriedades:

1. O código fica muito mais claro quando se utiliza propriedades (`property`).
2. Você pode alterar facilmente uma propriedade de "só leitura" para "Leitura e Escrita", e vice-versa, sem ter que ficar procurando no código os getters e setters.
3. Usando `INDEX` você pode passar um índice ao acessar as propriedades da classe;

   ```
   TMyRect = class
   private
     FValues: Array[0..3] of Integer;
     function GetTop(Index: Integer): Integer;
     function GetLeft(Index: Integer): Integer
     function GetWidth(Index: Integer): Integer
     function GetHeight(Index: Integer): Integer
   public
     property Top    Index 0 read GetTop;
     property Left   Index 1 read GetLeft;
     property Width  Index 2 read GetWidth;
     property Height Index 3 read GetHeight;
   end;


   function TMyRect.GetTop(Index: Integer): Integer;
   begin
     Result := FValues[Index];
   end;
   ```
4. Propriedades podem ser acessadas pelo Object Inspector;

Duas perguntas no SOen sobre esse assunto me ajudaram a aprender mais sobre:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391632/why-use-property-in-a-class

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963874/usage-of-property-vs-getters-setters-in-business-classes

Comment: Não sabia sobre o ***Index***, interessante. Acessa via ***object inspector*** as classes que foram instaladas no **Delphi** como componentes e que as propriedades estejam em ***published***.

Comment: @JamesTK Verdade, propriedades em published. Mas o mesmo não vale para campos (fields).

Answer (score 0):

Creio que a principal vantagem de se utilizar property ao invés de getter e setter em Delphi seja o acesso tanto de leitura como escrita em um único atributo.

Com getters e setters teríamos: getNome e setNome. (Exemplo: pessoa.setNome('Fulano'))

Com property teríamos: Nome apenas. (Exemplo: pessoa.nome := 'Fulano').

Nesse [link](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Property) existem mais informações úteis.